# Generating 4 Unique Numbers in a string

Tags: c#

I want to generate a string of 4 digits which the digits couldn't be replaced and used again, e.g. : 1234 is acceptable, 1223 is not!

P.S: I can't use while as my teacher asked me to! And no arrays or loops!

```
Random Item = new Random(); 
int Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4; 
do { 
    Num1 = Item.Next(0, 10); 
    Num2 = Item.Next(0, 10); 
    Num3 = Item.Next(0, 10); 
    Num4 = Item.Next(0, 10); 
} while (Num1 == Num2 || Num1 == Num3 
            || Num1 == Num4 || Num2 == Num3 
            || Num2 == Num4 || Num3 == Num4);

string Source = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: So what have you tried so far, what problems are you having with your solution, what aspects of this problem do you know how to solve and which do you not know how to solve, what resources have you looked at on how to solve this problem, and what problems have you had understanding them?

Comment: `return "1234";`

Comment: @doogle, yeah actually I tried so many times that I gave up! anything I tried so far has a while in it, I searched for a specific function, but couldn't find it so far! I thought of a random number between 1234 and 9876, but that won't guarantee its uniqueness!

Comment: @AtoosaMadadkar It'd help your question if you showed some code, even if it contained a while loop.

Comment: @doogle: `Random Item = new Random();
            int Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4;

            do
            {
                Num1 = Item.Next(0, 10);
                Num2 = Item.Next(0, 10);
                Num3 = Item.Next(0, 10);
                Num4 = Item.Next(0, 10);

            } while (Num1 == Num2 || Num1 == Num3 || Num1 == Num4 || Num2 == Num3 || Num2 == Num4 || Num3 == Num4);

            string Source = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4);`

Comment: I wouldn't trust a teacher that wants you to solve problems without using loops.  That's like asking you to dig a hole with a teaspoon even though you have a perfectly good shovel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Generate()
        {
            string remainingDigits = "0123456789";
            System.Random r = new System.Random();
            string output = null;
            int count = 10;
            int index = r.Next(count);
            output += remainingDigits[index];
            remainingDigits = remainingDigits.Remove(index, 1);
            count -= 1;
            index = r.Next(count);
            output += remainingDigits[index];
            remainingDigits = remainingDigits.Remove(index, 1);
            count -= 1;
            index = r.Next(count);
            output += remainingDigits[index];
            remainingDigits = remainingDigits.Remove(index, 1);
            count -= 1;
            index = r.Next(count);
            output += remainingDigits[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I took the cannot use WHILE as being not allowed to use a loop ... which is why the teacher specifically mentioned 4 digits.

Comment: Thank you, but my C# doesn't recognize most of the commands, should I use a different using?

Comment: The code above only has System added to Random.  There are no using statements needed.  Also this works for both .NET 4.5 and .NET 2.0.

Comment: Also .. the only reference I have for the class library is System (for .NET 2.0 anyways).

Comment: Which visual studio are u using?

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
var r = new Random();           
return new String("1234567890".OrderBy(x => r.Next()).Take(4).ToArray());
```

Comment: How can I use LINQ? sorry I'm naïve :(

Comment: `using System.Linq;` on the top of your file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            List<int> digits = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            Random ran = new Random();
            string ranString = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                int index = ran.Next(0, digits.Count);
                ranString += digits[index].ToString();
                digits.RemoveAt(index);
            }
```

Comment: If you don't want a loop then, use Marc's solution.   Basically the same code but no loop.